# Rsyslog error messages RHEL 7

Tags: linux, logging, rsyslog

We are facing many issues regarding journal error messages and we want to know how  to keep messages related to system in `/var/log/messages` and delete other messages?

Comment: This is a sysadmin question, not programming. And you should keep everything in the journal, and select (filter out) what you want to see (or not).

Answer (score 0):

As @vonbrand already mentioned in the comment, you usually do not want to delete messages from `/var/log/messages` (or probably any log file, for that matter), because you might loose important information.

What you can do instead is filter the output of log files with tools like `grep`. For example, if you only want lines from `/var/log/messages` that contain the character sequence *httpd*, you could achieve that with

```
grep "httpd" /var/log/messages
```

Note that `grep` [also supports regular expressions](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/grep-regular-expressions/) as search patterns.